Partial differential equation coming from integral of Bessel function
In this question, the solution $L_1(x,u)$ to the integral (probably, numerically) satisfies the partial differential equation
$$\frac{\partial^2 L_1}{\partial x \partial u} + xu L_1 = 0.$$
I am interested in whether this equation has been studied before. Whether it has a name, specific type, interpretations of solutions, etc. I am not an expert on PDEs but I understand that finding closed-form solutions is generally hopeless; any insight on the behaviour of this equation like that would also be interesting :) I am making this its own question because it is only incidental in the linked question and, while I hope understanding this equation will help with the previous question, it is also interesting on its own terms.
Apart from the solution in the linked question (which has lots of exponential integrals), the function $\mathrm{exp}(iux)/u$ is also a solution. The specific integral defining the function in the linked question is
$$ L_1(x,u) = x\int_0^{1} K_0\left( 2x \sqrt{r(1-r)} \right) \exp((2r-1)ixu) dr. $$
Here $K_0$ is the modified Bessel function. As noted in the previous question, replacing $K_0$ with $K_n$ or $I_n$ seems to give another solution to the PDE. One can also get a new solution from an old one by swapping $x$ and $u$.

Does separation of variables suggest a class of solutions?

I have tried to separate the variables but get stuck at a certain point. If $L(x,u) = f(x)g(u)$ then the equation becomes $f'(x)g'(u) + xuf(x)g(u)=0$. Then we have $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \frac{g'(u)}{g(u)} + xu = 0$. Integrating gives $\log(f(x)) \log(g(u)) + \frac{x^2u^2}{4} + r(x) + s(u) = 0$ for some auxiliary functions $r$ and $s$. But this product of logs does not seem very nice..

You probably want to review how the separation of variables technique goes.

You are right. On separating the variables I get $L(x,u) = \exp(\frac{cx^2}{2}-\frac{u^2}{2c})$ for a constant c.

The general solution is the linear combination of the particular solutions
$$L(x,u)=\displaystyle\sum_{\forall n}C_n e^{\frac{c_n}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2c_n}u^2}$$
with arbitrary constants $C_n$ and $c_n$ . Some of those constants can be complex thus introducing sinusoidal terms.

What is the sum indexed by? And why? is it $n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

@lewismcombes: At this point your boundary conditions will play a role. Replace the summation with an integral, at least formally, to have a broader class to explore.

@lewismcombes. In my above comment the solution is expressed on the form of a sum of discret particular solutions indexed with integers $n$. More generaly $$L(x,u)=\int C(\nu)e^{\frac{c(\nu)}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2c(\nu)}u^2}d\nu$$
$C(\nu)$ and $c(\nu)$ are arbitrary functions. Arbitrary functions and/or arbitrary constants are expected to be determined if some boundary conditions are specified. This is a much more arduous problem.
